# Kubernetes - Why Ingress resource is still marked as "beta"?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes 1.9 is now available.

However, Ingress resource is still marked as "beta" in the Kubernetes documentation (see
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ : "The Ingress is a beta resource, not available in any Kubernetes release prior to 1.1").

My questions are:

- Why is the Ingress resource marked as beta? Because some features are missing or because the API may change?
- Is it safe to use Ingress resources in a production Kubernetes cluster (on-premise cluster), especially with the official Nginx IngressControler (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually fine to use Kubernetes components that are [marked as beta](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#minor-version-scheme-and-timeline). The same is true for [API resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/):

> - Code is well tested. Enabling the feature is considered safe. Enabled by default.
> - Support for the overall feature will not be dropped, though details may change.

There is still a warning for incompatible changes in later releases:

> - Recommended for only non-business-critical uses because of potential for incompatible changes in subsequent releases. If you have multiple clusters which can be upgraded independently, you may be able to relax this restriction.

Regarding `NGINX Ingress Controller`: That is out of beta since [early December](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.9.0).